# Explicitly defining line styles in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to plot a couple sets of data together in seaborn and I want the related columns to be the same color, but one of them dashed and one solid.
I currently have the data in 4 separate pandas data frames. All 4 have the z-coordinate column (x variable) + 1 density column (y variable):

```
print(FO_CUR_edit1.head())
```

```
In [64]: runcell('**comparative plot: CUR + Ester groups from CUR sims, and water from protein sims**', '/Users/billystone/Desktop/MD_sims/Comparative Analysis/Partial Densities.py')
   z-coordinate (nm)  Curcumin with FO
0           0.111137               0.0
1           0.333410               0.0
2           0.555684               0.0
3           0.777957               0.0
4           1.000230               0.0
```

Here is my function I used to plot the data:

```
def density_plot(sim_name, master_data):

    (sns.lineplot(x = "z-coordinate (nm)", y = "Density $(kg m^{-3})$", hue = "Group",
                data = pd.melt(master_data,
                         ["z-coordinate (nm)"],
                         var_name = "Group",
                         value_name = "Density $(kg m^{-3})$"))
    .set_title("Average Densities Perpendicular to\n Membrane Axis for " + sim_name))
    plt.ylim(-30, 1050)
    plt.xlim(0, 11.5)


density_plot("Partial Denisties of CUR", FO_CUR_edit1)
density_plot("", DMPG_CUR_edit1)
density_plot("", FO_CUR_edit2)
density_plot("", DMPG_CUR_edit2)
```

which results in this plot:

[image: density data]

I want to have the two 'curcumin' data sets to be the same color, but one solid line and one dashed. I want the 'ester' groups to be the same way, but with a second color. I tried concatenating the data frames and that didn't work as seaborn applies the linestyle to every line in the plot. I also tried specifying the color by using a 'with' statement, but that also didn't work as I didnt know how to also specify line type using that. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include part of `FO_CUR_edit1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `lineplot` You need to reorganize your dataframe in 'long-form'. That is, it should have four columns `[z,density,Curcumin/Esther,FO/protein]` where you four datasets are concatenated and the last two columns indicate your groups.

Then you can use a single `lineplot` call like so:

```
sns.lineplot(data=<dataframe>, x='z', y='density',
             hue='Curcumin/Esther', style='FO/protein', dashes=True, markers=False)
```

See the examples using both `hue` and `style` in [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html?highlight=lineplot#seaborn.lineplot)